# Analytic function or not?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $f(t) = 1 + e^{2\pi i \phi t}$ a complex analytic function? $t\in\mathbb{R},\phi\in\mathbb{Z},i=\sqrt{-1}$. I know this could be an easy question, but I just want to make sure that the 1 does not influence the analyticity of $e$.

Comment: A **complex** analytic function is usually defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about a complex-analytic function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry is it a real analytic function?

Comment: It is not a real analytic function, as its image is not in $\mathbb{R}$. It is not a complex analytic function, as its domain is not an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. But, as a function from a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, it may make sense to ask if it **can be extended** to an analytic function on some subset of $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: In the case of Rellich's theorem $\mathbf{A}(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ people talk about the analycity of the entry functions $a_{ij}(t):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$? How does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(t) = 1 + e^{2\pi i\phi t}$ is not a *complex analytic* function, since by definition, a complex analytic function is defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (or, more generally, of a complex manifold). $f$ has a complex analytic extension (to an entire function), it is the restriction of a complex analytic function to the domain $\mathbb{R}$. As such, it is a *complex valued* **real-analytic** function. Or, if we don't want to stress that it is complex valued, simply a real-analytic function.

Since the domain is $\mathbb{R}$, speaking of analyticity cannot mean complex analyticity, hence it is also legitimate to simply call it an analytic function, but that opens the door for confusion, so it is preferable to be explicit and call it real-analytic.